# How do I change what appears on a node in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

When I create a node with some properties and display it, it displays the node with the value of 1st property on it. I want to display some name or some value on it instead of 1st property value. 
[image]

Also, what is the procedure if I want to represent a node with some image?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I want to display some name or some value on it instead of 1st
>   property value.

In Neo4j 3.2.1 you can click in a label (top of image) and after it select the caption property (bottom of image).

[image: Neo4j browser]

> Also, what is the procedure if I want to represent a node with some
>   image?

Is not possible present an image within the node in Neo4j browser.

Comment: What about representing it with an image?

Comment: I believe that is not possible present an image within the node, but you can change the node color of in the bar shown in the bottom of image posted here.